# Renting a road or mountainbike in Pescara region

Tags: italy, rental, sport

I would like to rent a proper road or mountain bike in August when travelling to Pescar, Italy.
All I have found online are either "normal" bike rentals, i.e. trekking or utility bikes, or generic websites that claim to ship road bikes to the destinations.
I would prefer a local bike rental with adequate prices.

Comment: For something specialized like this, you may have better luck renting in Rome (or another large city you travel through) and bringing it with you on the train or car than rending in Pescara directly.

Comment: Try Yelp or TripAdvisor (they suggest [these people](https://www.activeabruzzo.com/location/) but I've no idea how good they are). You may have to contact places to ask what they have available, but cycle tourism seems popular in the area.

Comment: Try the decathlon rent service, I've never tested it, but probably it's the simpler way for rent a bike in a non-italian language from the web. Try select different stores, the availability varys: https://rent.decathlon.it/en/wizard/map?addressInput=Pescara%2C+Italia&autocomplete_latitude=42.2646675&autocomplete_longitude=13.9609912&sport-list_selected=6&range_date-from=2022-07-01&range_date-to=2022-07-03

Comment: Thanks, decathlon looks reasonable, they even offer klick pedals